# Safely deleting portalvhds storage from my Azure account without messing anything up

Tags: azure

I'm attempting to tidy up my Azure account and notice I have a storage service beginning portalvhds still set up and running.

Am I right in believing this storage is used only for VM disks (I've since removed all VMs from my account)? Or is it possible this storage is where other services (e.g. SQL Databases or websites) that I'm still using might be stored. Basically, are non-VM services held completely separate to my storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Database doesn't use Storage, your databases were stored in dedicate clusters. Ref website, it depends on if you are using this storage in your code. So if you can make sure you didn't use this storage in your code, in website or cloud service roles, I think you can delete them.

PS: You can specify link resource in website portal, which will be more easily to observe if it's being used or not.

Comment: Excellent- thanks for the information and reassurance :)